# Laravel echo server console says left the channel and again joins the channel while navigating through pages?

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, laravel-5.4, laravel-echo

I am trying to add realtime functionality to my `laravel` app which is being developed in `laravel-5.4`.
So, I have implemented a simple chat example from the documentation
that is `laravel-echo-server` with `redis` and `socket.io`. It’s working fine but I have noticed a weird behaviour that is when the user navigates to different pages across the application, the **laravel-echo-server** console says `left the channel` and again `joined the channel` so is it intended behaviour and what is the best practise to use it. am i doing something wrong here? I don't want him to left the channel, instead I want to stay him at the same connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change page, everything is lost and a new content is dowloaded from the server. So it's normal that the user "left the channel" then re"joined the channel". It's the intended behavior.

If you don't want this kind of behavior, you have to stay one the same page (so implementing something like a single page application). Because when you leave a page to go to another, current scripts stops then a new world is re-created.

Comment: thanks for your information So that means I will have to stick with frontend frameworks like `Vue.JS`? so if the user open via different tab then we have no-control over it

Comment: @msonowal did I answer your question?